# How to place Walmart pickup orders as a traveler?

Tags: usa, shopping

When placing a Walmart pickup order as a non-us resident traveling the us you need to specify a US billing address and US phone number. How should you use this service without those things. From experience if you order using the address and phone number of your hotel you will end up with your order cancelled.

Best buy in contrast mentions on their order form that you have to use a special address they provide you with if you're an international customer. Does something similar exist for Walmart?

Comment: Note: there was no issue with the financial transaction itself, the error message was explicit in claiming the billing address or phone number couldn't be verified. I have no idea what this practically entails. If I don't get an answer here I will call them (and self answer), but considering how expensive such international calls are I am giving this a go first.

Comment: You can also contact their support by email or chat, if phone is not an option...

Comment: You can get a [free DID](https://www.voip-info.org/cheapest-atas-and-service) from a number of providers. Then you can [set up](https://support.google.com/phoneapp/answer/2811843?hl=en) your phone to use the VoIP providers of your choice. Try [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) if you have an iPhone and need to set up VoIP on it.

Comment: Have you tried using a pre paid debit card to avoid issues with non matching addresses with customer not present card transactions?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold.